# React Router - Invalid prop `children` supplied to `Router` when composing routes

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

Why is it that when I supply the routes within the router all is good but when I compose the routes like below I get a

`warning.js:36 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop`children`supplied to`Router`.
        in Router (at index.js:62)
        in Root (at index.js:70)`

and a

`browser.js:49 Warning: [react-router] Location "/contact" did not match any routes`

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, Link, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

class Navigation extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><Link to='/'>Main</Link></li>
          <li><Link to='/about'>About</Link></li>
          <li><Link to='/contact'>Contact</Link></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

class Contact extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Contact</div>;
  }
}

class About extends Component {
  render() {
    return ( <div>About</div> );
  }
}

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Home</div>;
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>App</h1>
        <Navigation />
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


const routes = () => (
  <Route path='/' component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Home} />
    <Route path='about' component={About} />
    <Route path='contact' component={Contact} />
  </Route>
)

export default class Root extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        {routes}
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Root  />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

I've tried just about all variations. Is it possible to compose routes? Any 
help appreciated.

Comment: The way we do this is just doing `const routes = ( // routes go here )` without the arrow function. what happens if you remove the arrow function

Comment: If you put a preceding `/` in `<Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />` does that help?

Comment: you *can* have `routes` be a function, but you'll need to call it `{routes()}`

Comment: I agree with @finalfreq, your `routes` shouldn't be a function, just a const. Or, if you want it to be a function for some reason, in `Root` you need to make it `{routes()}`

Comment: What version of react-router are you using?

Answer (score 1):

```js
export default class Root extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        {routes()}
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```